# Apple Script to close all windows in Finder — but keep active window AND ITS TABS open?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript

I would like to close all Finder windows but keep the active one open – included keeping all its tabs open also. AppleScript are from Mars and it seems I’m from Venus, but
I’ve found some ready made scripts around the web. I get them all to close all windows and keep the active window open, but they also close the tabs of the active window.

I'm on MacOS Catalina 10.15.7
Here’s some of the scripts I’ve tried. Any tips appreciated!

```
tell application "Finder"
    repeat while window 2 exists
    close window 2
    end repeat
    end tell
```

---

```
tell application "Finder"   
    set theWindows to {}
    set theCount to (count of windows)
    if theCount is greater than 1 then
        repeat with i from 2 to theCount
            set theWindow to window i
            copy theWindow to end of theWindows
        end repeat
        close theWindows
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: A tab is just a window that’s linked afaik. If I’m wrong, however you are in the correct spot for a more proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

In basic *vanilla* **AppleScript** there is no `property`, `element` or `class` for a *tab* in a  *window* in **Finder**, and as such it makes it difficult to tell if a *window* presents with multiple *tabs* at the **UI** level, (multiple `windows` presented as *tabs* within a single **UI** level *window*).

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is a bit kludgy as it can/will minimize and un-minimize the visible front **UI** level *window*, however, is does close all other `windows` not within the *window* that is frontmost and visible at the **UI** level at the time the *code* is run.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application id "com.apple.finder"
    if (count windows) is less than or equal to 1 then return
    set collapsedWindows to windows whose collapsed is true
    close collapsedWindows
    if (count windows) is greater than 1 then
        set collapsed of window 1 to true
        set uncollapsedWindows to windows whose collapsed is false
        close uncollapsedWindows
        set collapsed of window 1 to false
    end if
end tell
```

**Notes:**

What the *example* **AppleScript** *code* does:

- Checks the number of `windows` for *error handling* purposes.
- Closes all `windows` that are currently minimized (`collapsed:true`).
- Then if more than one `window`, minimizes the front *window*.
- Closes all `windows` that are not currently minimized (`collapsed:false`).
- Un-minimizes the one remaining *window* (`windows` where  `collapsed:true`).

Note that if there is only one *window* in **Finder** with multiple *tabs* and is minimized when the *code* is run it will close that *window*, however, I take this condition to be outside the scope of the intent of the question, as the keyword use in the OP was "active" and a minimized *window* is not considered the "active" *window* in normal context.  This is also an unfortunate consequence of there not being a `tab` as a `property`, `element` or `class` for a *tab* in a  *window* in **Finder**.

<sup>Note that terms used in the paragraphs above shown as, e.g. `window` are referring to them programmatically and shown as e.g. *window* are referring to them at the **UI** level.</sup>

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in **Script Editor** under every version of **macOS** from **macOS Sierra** to **macOS Monterey** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

The following produces a list of all windows. It then creates a second list of containing every item from the first list except the frontmost window. Finally, it closes every item of the second list. It works in Sierra.

```
tell application "Finder"
    
    set allWin to windows
    set winRest to rest of allWin
    close winRest
end tell
```

It will fail if you have 0 or 1 window open but you can easily add some error handling for that.

FWIW, I don't think you can manipulate Finder window tabs using applescript.

Comment: The OP is running **macOS Catalina** and this does not work in **macOS Mojave** and later. You should come into the twenty-first century so to speak and upgrade to a more recent version of **macOS**.

Answer (score -2):

I can't find a way to distinguish a tab from a window. Is there any? Maybe not. As bmike mentioned, a tab is a window. If Finder's windows have identical window positions and identical window sizes there's high probability that the window is a tab. However that's not always true.

The following script will work as long as two windows dont have identical windows positions:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set frontPosition to (position of (front window))
    set frontBounds to (bounds of (front window))
    
    repeat with i from (count of windows) to 1 by -1
        if (frontPosition ≠ (position of (window i)) or frontBounds ≠ (bounds of (window i))) then
            close window i
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: If there is a `window` with `collapsed:true` when the _code_ is run then it fails as it then closes all but one `window`. In other words, it close all but one `window` of the multiple `windows` presented as _tabs_ within a single **UI** level _window_. Which of course the OP does not want to have happen.

Comment: That's not entirely true, it closes non active ones, and keeps the tabs. Let's say you have 2 collapsed windows and each one has 2 tabs, the script will close one window and leave the other one collapsed with 2 tabs in it.

Comment: Gintaras, The statement I made in my first comment **is in fact true** in general for all versions of **macOS** prior to **macOS Monterey** and in **macOS Big Sur** it fails under certain conditions, not counting no `windows`. In my testing the _code_, as is, fails to achieve that stated goal in the OP running **macOS Catalina**, under the conditions tested. Certainly there must be good reasons why the answer has received two down-votes. BTW The _code_ also throws an error if there are no `windows` opened in **Finder**, a minor point but that is what _error handling_ is for, and there is none.